# What is the Test ID number of the USB7216 USB Hub chip

Tags: usb, integrated-circuit, datasheet, microchip

I am using the Microchip USB7216 USB 3.2 Hub chip in my design. I would like to know the TID number of this part. I have looked in the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/00003143B.pdf), on the [manufacturer's website](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/USB7216#document-table), and the [internet in general](https://www.google.com/search?q=usb7216%20%22TID%22%20number), but cannot seem to find it.

1. Should I expect to find the TID number in the device's datasheet?
2. It is normal for manufacturers to publish the TID of a USB chip?
3. If I can't find the TID, does this imply that it hasn't been through compliance testing?

Comment: use better key word searches https://www.google.com/search?q=usb+Microchip+%22TID%22+number&sxsrf=APq-WBsUaQ6ntbvag2B7VzscenoYdjbpZQ%3A1648045088620&ei=ICw7YoCsJZGO9PwP3oy7sAs&ved=0ahUKEwiAvNKwttz2AhURB50JHV7GDrYQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=usb+Microchip+%22TID%22+number&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BggAEAcQHjoECAAQHkoECEEYAUoECEYYAFDPCFiAEGDoGGgBcAB4AIABbYgB0wGSAQMwLjKYAQCgAQGgAQLAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test ID is governed by USB-IF consortium. They issue and publish the TID if a product passes a comprehensive set of tests in Certified Labs. Go  usb-if.org . You might need to have a legal account to search their database, for which you might need to pay a membership fee.

Generally you can't sell a chip to a reputable company if you don't pass USB-IF certification (they simply won't buy it).

Result from https://www.usb.org/products:
[image]